# Laravel 5 Displaying related model data on blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I would like to create an eager loading on my model but I keep getting and error. Anyways here is my model structure

```
// table name is drug_logs
class DrugLog extends Model
{
    public function drug() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Drug');
    }

    public function dispensedDrug() {
      return $this->hasOne('App\DispensedDrug');
    }
}

// table name is drugs
class Drug extends Model
{
    public function drugLogs() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\DrugLog');
    }
}
// table name is dispensed_drugs
class DispensedDrug extends Model
{
    public function drugLog() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\DrugLog');
    }
}
```

But now on my controller I tried using this function

```
$drug_logs = DrugLog::with('dispensed_drugs')->get();
```

But I keep getting an error

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2003: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::dispensed_drugs()
```

Any idea on this guys?

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Yes this is the error Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Library/WebServer/Documents/project/resources/views/drug/details.blade.php)

And its pointing on the {{ $log->dispensedDrug()->name }} part

Comment: You should use {{$log->dispensedDrug->name}}, check your database maybe you dont't have related data in db

Comment: OMG... It's just a missing entry on my dispensed_drug table. It's looking for id 40 and couldn't find it :( anyways yeah what you suggested also works. Thanks again for pointing out about this database issue

Comment: `$drug_logs = DrugLog::with('dispensed_drugs')->get();` should be `$drug_logs = DrugLog::with('dispensedDrug')->get();` referencing the method dispensedDrug in your DrugLog model.